# Getting wrong answer should be 6, but I am getting 548

Tags: c++

I am getting a wrong answer.I should get 6, but I am getting 548.

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

//Fuction of add
int add(int x,int y)
{
return x+y;
}

//Function of multiply calling add fuction
int mul(int x,int y)
{
cout << add(2,3);
return x*y;
}

//Main Function
int main()
{
cout << mul(6,8);
return 0;
}
```

Comment: why are you expecting 6? change the line cout << add(2,3); to  
cout << add(2,3)<<endl; and see.

Answer (score 1):

You are getting what you have programmed. 
first the result of addition which is `2 + 3 = 5` and then the result of multiplication `6 * 8 = 48`.

Since you are not giving providing escape characters the result is being printed right beside each other.

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

//Fuction of add
int add(int x,int y)
{
    return x+y;
}

//Function of multiply calling add fuction
int mul(int x,int y)
{
    cout << "Addition of 2 and 3 is "<< add(2,3) << "\n";
    return x*y;
}


//Main Function
int main()
{
   cout << "Multiplication of 6 and 8 is "<<mul(6,8)<<"\n";
   return 0;
}
```

By providing statements will help you better understand your program.

Answer (score 0):

`mul(6,8)` outputs the result of `add(2,3)`, i.e. 5, and then returns the result of 6*8, which is 48. That result is printed by main. Since there are no intervening spaces or newlines, what you see is `548.`

Answer (score 0):

I think you can solve this problem yourself if you add a newline to each `cout` statement: `cout << add(2,3) << endl;`